# cant connect to common library in weblogic

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, weblogic

i'm trying to connect to an EJB that is located in a common library in weblogic from my ear. The problem is that when i start the application on weblogic, i get a classNotFoundException and the specified class is the ejb interface. If I add the ejb to my ear, then i can connect to it without problems, but when referring the CommonJars( the library name) i get that error.

```
<library-ref>
        <library-name>CommonJars</library-name>
        <specification-version>1.0</specification-version>
        <implementation-version>1.0</implementation-version>
        <exact-match>true</exact-match>
</library-ref>
```

that's how i refer the library.

```
<bean id="ExampleServiceEJB" class="org.springframework.ejb.access.SimpleRemoteStatelessSessionProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="something.ejb.aham.ExampleService#com.something.something.that.job.ExampleService" />
        <property name="businessInterface" value="com.something.something.that.job.ExampleService" />
</bean>
```

that is how I connect to the ejb (yeah, im using spring).

Answer (score 0):

Configure `prefer-application-packages` in `weblogic-application.xml`.

```
<weblogic-application ...>
    ....
    <prefer-application-packages> 
        <package-name>com.my.example.*</package-name> 
    </prefer-application-packages> 
</weblogic-application>
```

Comment: But will that actually work? since the EJB i'm referring to is not in my application

Comment: your EAR don't `weblogic-application.xml` ?